# use advance custom field inside query post command

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I can't find a solutions in internet or advance custom field website docs about this. I hope wordpress genius can help me.

I use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ for themes options/function.
I want to show category post in homepage using category name. here is my code:

```
<!-- Start Category Posts -->
<div class="boxtype2">
    <div class="boxtitle1"><?php the_field('cat_1'); ?></div>
    <div class="boxposts">
    <?php query_posts('category_name=<?php the_field('cat_1_name'); ?>','showposts=5'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <!-- article -->
        <ul class="boxul">
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <br class="clear">
        </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /article -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <!-- article -->
        <article>
            <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'fileketchup' ); ?></h2>
        </article>
        <!-- /article -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="boxfooter"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/<?php the_field('view_cat1'); ?>">View more</a></div>
</div>
<!-- End Category Posts -->
```

Please check 
    `<?php query_posts('category_name=<?php the_field('cat_1_name'); ?>','showposts=5'); ?>`
this...

Here I use advance custom field meta insert of category name.. but its show error... How I solve this?? If I use **('category_name=blog','showposts=5')** then its works.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Specifically, that is not how you concatenate a [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in PHP.

Comment: please give me correct syntax.

Comment: Avoid using `query_posts`, use `WP_Query` instead, read this [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/22534) for more information on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=<?php the_field('cat_1_name'); ?>','showposts=5'); ?>
```

The string argument is literally `category_name=<?php the_field('cat_1_name'); ?>','showposts=5`. Well, it would be if the string were not also triggering a fatal error.

What you have is (assuming I haven't lost track of the mess):

- String 1: `'category_name=<?php the_field('cat_1_name');
  ?>','showposts=5'`
- An undefined constant: cat_1_name
- An out of place comma, making what follows a second argument to a
  function that only takes one argument: `,`
- And String 2: `'showposts=5'`

That is never going to work. If you are going to be writing code you need to learn to create strings in PHP. That has got to be in the first five things you should learn to do well.

Secondly, you are not in `HTML` context so you do not need to be using PHP open and close tags at all, and doing so will trigger further fatal errors.

Third, you are mixing up `array` syntax with the hard-to-read-and-hard-to-edit-and-prone-to-error query-string-like syntax that is mysteriously popular in WordPress.

Fourth, AFC's `the_field` `echo`s content. You can't use that to concatenate a string anyway. You need `get_field`.

Fifth, `showposts` has been deprecated for a very long time. Use `posts_per_page`.

Strings that should work:

`"category_name=".get_field('cat_1_name')."&posts_per_page=5"`
`'category_name='.get_field('cat_1_name').'&posts_per_page=5'`

But don't use that query-string syntax, create an array.

```
$args = array(
  'category_name' => get_field('cat_1_name'),
  'posts_per_page' => 5
);
```

And finally, [please don't use `query_posts`.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/21376)

> It should be noted that using this to **replace the main query** on a page
>   can **increase page loading times**, in worst case scenarios **more than
>   doubling the amount of work needed or more**. While easy to use, the
>   function is also **prone to confusion and problems** later on. See the
>   note further below on caveats for details.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

As s_ha_dum said, your syntax is wrong. You should work like this:

```
'key' => 'value',
```

Try modifying your query_posts loop to:

to:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'cat_1_name',
    'posts_per_page' => 5);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <!-- article -->
    <ul class="boxul">
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <br class="clear">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /article -->
<?php endwhile;
} else {
    ?>
    <!-- article -->
        <article>
            <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'fileketchup' ); ?></h2>
        </article>
        <!-- /article -->
    <?php }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

If you need your category name to be from your custom field, you can set it as a variable, and call that variable as the value for 'category_name'. Something like this:

```
$category = get_field('cat_1_name');

$args = array(
    'category_name' => $category,
    'posts_per_page' => 5);
```

**EDIT:** I edited because the above comments are spot on. You've no need to use query_posts. If you need more $args for your WP_Query, [go read up on it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)!